# Spell check not working in parts of Texmaker after copy and paste

Tags: texmaker, spelling

I am using Texmaker 4.5 on Windows 10 and the built-in spell-checker stops working if I copy and paste a section into the document. It seems to work/not-work on a paragraph by paragraph basis. If I try to spell-check a non-working section I am told that no misspelled words were detected, even if I have complete gibberish in the paragraph.

The figure below shows the issue I am having, see how the three gibberish words above the citation are not marked as misspelled, while the words below are correctly tagged with a red line.

[image]

Additionally, it appears that if I use `\cite{}` in the section that was once copied into the document the spell checker works until I close the brackets. For example, here is a working spell-checker[image]

and here is a unworking spell-checker. [image]

All I did was close the bracket and the spell checker stopped working.

I have checked this the same document on my laptop running texmaker 4.1 on a Linux platform and it works perfectly.

Comment: I cannot verify on windows machine, Makesure the path to `.dic` file  in Spelling Dictionary  is properly placed and the right language is chosen based on your preference. Go to File Menu of Texmaker --> Options-> Configure Texmaker-->Editor--> Spelling Dictionary.  WARNING(you will loose your settings if you proceed in this way): on worst case scenario restart the texmaker Reset settings of Texmaker

Comment: I did check that the dictionary is properly placed and I reset the setting of TexMaker.  My next step is to reinstall the program, however, while working on the problem I downloaded TeXstudio. I have to say that I am very happy with this "interim" solution.

Comment: I have a similar problem! It's probably a bug in the Linux version

Comment: This may well be the same issue as https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/444349/35864, which will be resolved in the next version of TeXmaker. If you can consistently reproduce this weird behaviour I think it is fair to assume this is a bug that should have been reported to the developers. In cases like this there is often little that can be done on this site. Work-arounds often have disadvantages and the developers should know about this.

Answer (score 1):

I am a beginner user of LaTex, so apologies if the answer is not professional, but it solved my problem.

I had the same issue and tried to update to the latest version (5.0.2) of Texmaker but no luck. I was using {natbib} package and the command \cite{..}.

However, when I changed the citation package from \usepackage{natbib} to \usepackage{apacite} and only use \citeA{...} or citeNP{...} commands the spelling check starts to work as normal. Even with the {apacite} package the issue still appears if I use the command \cite{..}.

I hope this might encourage expert users to give a detailed answer!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! A workaround is better than nothing!

Answer (score 1):

A simple workaround to fix the issue is as follows:

I am using TexMaker 5.0.2 with Bibtex and IEEEtran style. In my .tex file, what I realized is that sentences/paragraphs before `\cite` are not spellchecked. See:

[image: spellcheck is off]

What I do is simply press Enter (new line) before the `\cite` command and continue the sentence. You should do it for each and every `\cite` command.

[image: spellcheck is up and running]