# texMaker Mac Spell Checking not working before \parencite

Tags: biblatex, texmaker, spelling

more like a "Bug"-Report, but maybe anyone knows a good workaround?

I use latest texMaker on Mac, with `biblatex` and using `\parencite{}`. It seems the spellchecking ignores everything before the `\parencite{}`.

See example Image, marked text gets ignored and after `\parentcite{}` it works.

[image: parentcite and spellchecking, texMaker]

**EDIT: Thanks for the quick response! Here are some more minimal tests.**

[image: testing various methods]

Texmaker 5.0.2

Packages:

```
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[]{multicol}
\usepackage[nameinlink,noabbrev, english]{cleveref}
\usepackage{blindtext}
```

and a few PDF Packages, if needed I can give full list.

Cheers
Hannes

Comment: If you can consistently reproduce this you should *definitely* report this to the TeXmaker developers.

Comment: added more Information, could be related with this [spell-check-not-working-in-parts-of-texmaker-after-copy-and-paste](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/369866/spell-check-not-working-in-parts-of-texmaker-after-copy-and-paste?rq=1)

Comment: I see, I can reproduce the behaviour now as well. The developers should definitely know about this, submit a bug report even if you do get a work-around here.

Comment: Ok did send TeXmaker a short mail, thanks for testing it.

Comment: As an aside: You should not be using ``\\`` to end a paragraph. In fact you should not be using ``\\`` outside a table or other special environments ever - ``\\`` in normal text are almost always a really bad idea. You start a new paragraph by leaving a blank line in the code or with `\par` if you insist. If you don't like the paragraph indentations, there are ways to get rid of it, but open any book on your desk and you have a 87% chance that it uses paragraph indents and not vertical space to mark new paragraphs.

Comment: Thanks pretty new to LaTeX so all tips are more than welcome

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in TeXmaker's spell checking engine. TeXmaker seems to more or less consistently ignore all text in a line leading up to a `\cite...` like command if there is a `\cite...` command in a line. The OP has already reported this to the developers and has been promised a fix for the next release in late August or September.

A few possible work-arounds

- The spell checking will kick in again if one of the two optional arguments is given (it may be empty), so you can write `\cite[]{sigfridsson}` instead of `\cite{sigfridsson}` and should be good.
- Some `\cite` commands don't suffer from this behaviour, `\citep` for example is fine. So with `natbib` compatibility mode ([Is there a disadvantage to using natbib=true with biblatex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/149313/35864)) you can trick TeXmaker into working again.
- Move each `\cite` into a new line
- Use a different editor. TeXStudio is similar to TeXmaker and is more customisable in many respects. See also [LaTeX Editors/IDEs](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/339/35864)

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=authoryear, backend=biber, natbib]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
lorem amen lorem amen lorem \textit{sigfridsson} lorem

lorem amen lorem amen lorem \cite{sigfridsson} lorem

lorem amen lorem amen lorem \parencite{sigfridsson} lorem

% work-around 1
lorem amen lorem \cite[]{sigfridsson} lorem

% work-around 2
lorem amen lorem \citep{sigfridsson} lorem

% work-around 3
lorem ipsum lorem
\cite{sigfridsson}
\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot of TeXmaker with spellcheck enabled]

Comment: Got following Mail answer devs of maker:
It will be fixed in the next release (end of august or september)

Best regards.

Comment: @HannesOberreiter Thanks for reporting this. I edited that into the answer.