# Auto-correct from Texmaker when using \cite

Tags: citing, texmaker

I have a question about the TexMaker editor. In some cases the auto correct does not find typing errors in the script, and I don't know why, it seems strange to me, but seems to be linked to the use of citations. Here a screenshot of the problem.

[image]

Have you encoutered such a problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution at this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/444369/193622). This is a bug in spell checking engine of TeXmaker.

> A few possible work-arounds:
>
> - The spell checking will kick in again if one of the two optional arguments is given (it may be empty), so you can write `\cite[]{sigfridsson}` instead of `\cite{sigfridsson}` and should be good.
> - Some `\cite` commands don't suffer from this behaviour, `\citep` for example is fine. So with `natbib` compatibility mode ([Is there a disadvantage to using natbib=true with biblatex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/149313/35864)) you can trick TeXmaker into working again.
> - Move each `\cite` into a new line
> - Use a different editor. TeXStudio is similar to TeXmaker and is more customisable in many respects. See also [LaTeX Editors/IDEs](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/339/35864)